# In Finder, Mac showing under Devices "Update"?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem, error, hacking

[image][image: new][image: newlog_frominstaller][image]I just downgraded from Big Sur to High Sierra and now in the Finder menu, it is showing Remote Disc and Update. I have attached an image, is this normal ???

[image: partition]

also found this unusual

[image: help]

[image: Update?]

[image: partition scheme]

does this look right ?

Comment: Remote disc is normal, you had that in High Sierra before.  "Update" is showing up because instead of erasing the entire disk device before installing High Sierra, instead you erased parts of the container group.  "Update" is from Big Sur.

Comment: can I remove "update" @MarcWilson

Comment: Can you add to your question, the text results of terminal command : `diskutil list`? It's to see the actual disk organisation and all volumes.

Comment: @Jean_JD I have attached a screenshot above. thanks for responding

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade to big Sur now via high Sierra and getting alot of strange messages in the Installer Log::

Sep 27 23:43:51 toms-MBP osinstallersetupd[1553]: Retrying http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/38/071-97382-A_OEKYSXCO6D/97vrhncortwd3i38zfogcscagmpwksdzce/InstallAssistant.pkg after 1 failure(s): Error Domain=PKDownloadError Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fec91ddabe0 {Error Domain=PKDownloadError Code=14 "(null)"}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two volumes unnecessary (Big Sur remains) :

**Macintosh - HD Data disk1s5**

and

**Updates disk1s6**

You can delete this with terminal commands :

```
diskutil umount disk1s5

diskutil umount disk1s6
```

Then

```
diskutil ap deletevolume disk1s5

diskutil ap deletevolume disk1s6
```

Comment: I have attached a new log screen shot from the installer, are you sure if I delete the volume it won't screw up the current installation I'm trying to achieve , is the installer stalling because of the problem you have listed ? thanks for the help. I'm in the middle of trying to install the upgrade but I keep getting the strange messages in the installer log as listed. sorry to repeat myself.

Comment: Can you specify what you want to update?
Are you ok with High Sierra there?
If so you can (must) delete these 2 unnecessary volumes.

Comment: i just did what you said and did those 4 commands in terminal. I'm currently on high Sierra and trying to update to big Sur via the App Store. 

the Macintosh HD - data 
Update 

has been now removed from finder after those 4 commands

Comment: Can you add now the results of command `diskutil list`?

Comment: sure I just attached a screenshot

Comment: It's ok now. If you want upgrade to Big Sur you can now try with AppStore.

Comment: Sep 28 18:03:03 toms-MBP system_installd[469]: PackageKit: ensureRecoveryBooter started.
Sep 28 18:03:08 toms-MBP system_installd[469]: PackageKit: ensureRecoveryBooter succeeded
Sep 28 18:03:09 toms-MBP system_installd[469]: PackageKit: ----- End install -----
 just got this message from the installer log but nothing. happened and the big Sur installer GUI still sats 2 hours and 40 minutes and has been frozen on that for over a hour

Comment: Can you reboot your Mac? Then Reset SMC, Reset NVRAM, then try re-run Big Sur upgrade. Else the best way is, after doing a Time Machine Save or better a Carbon Copy Cloner clone on external disk, create an Big Sur Installer on USB Key and doing a clean install of Big Sur (after erase the disk) and retrieve your data by the Migration Assistant : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204350 using the external save (TM or CCC).

Comment: thanks for all the help the installer log now says it is downloading. hopefully it will work this time I have been through 40GB of data today trying to update.... each attempt has been over 12GB. do you think it should work this time ? Sep 28 18:26:43 toms-MBP osinstallersetupd[618]: Started downloading package com.apple.pkg.InstallAssistant.macOSBigSur (http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/57/38/071-97382-A_OEKYSXCO6D/97vrhncortwd3i38zfogcscagmpwksdzce/InstallAssistant.pkg)

Comment: // my Macintosh HD is saying its used 40gb of 128GB :/ perhaps a fresh install ,might be best , but I might let it run and see if its works this time around as the installer GUI is already running . if all else fails perhaps tomorrow I shall try the method you advised. thanks for the all the help much appriciated for lending your time to help me :)

Comment: If the install is ok, you don't have to do a clean install. I hope it will be fine now. ;-}

Comment: thanks Jean_JD ! I is it possible my firewall was blocking the update ? if I have deny all on ?

Comment: hi jean the upgrade worked but now in finder it doesn't show Macintosh HD - Data , is it meant to show in finder ? or do I have to mount it for it to be viewable I'm just worried that my partition is configured wrong now. the system appears to be running fine but I think its missing ( Macintosh HD - Data, I have attached a new screen shot of the nee partition scheme does that look right ?

Comment: Hi @newmacuser123. Great. I'm happy for you. It is quite normal that the Machintosh HD - Data volume does not appear in the Finder. On the other hand Macintosh HD must appear aggregating the contents of the 2 Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD - Data volumes. This breakdown into 2 volumes is explained by Apple's choice to have made the system volume read-only, for security reasons, and thus to have separated it from that of user data.